# Is it possible to get an ELB's ip address even if direct access is blocked by cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

our servers are load balanced by an ELB. We blocked direct access to the ELB's ip address using CloudFlare. However, we seem to be getting rom-0 requests/attacks and we're not sure how they're able to get an IP address that directly accesses our load balancer. Is this possible? We're trying to stop this from happening.

Comment: *"We blocked direct access to the ELB's ip address using CloudFlare."*  There seems to be a flawed assumption behind this statement.  Nothing you could do in Cloudflare itself would "block direct access" to an ELB for anyone who was just scanning IP address ranges.  Have you restricted your ELB's security group to only accept traffic from [Cloudflare's source IP addresses](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)?

Comment: Ah, no. But that makes a lot of sense. Let me try that. And thanks for the link to CloudFlare.